# How to apply straight border color to a rounded div in css

Tags: css

There.

Just wondering, How do you style a straight border-color to a rounded div in css, here i have some simple tailwindcss.

```
<div class="rounded-2xl w-72 h-20 border-l-4 border-l-yellow-500">
...
</div>
```

from code above, i get a result of left yellow border which is fine, but since i apply rounded-2xl, the border seems curved from inside. how do you get straight-line border instead but while still aplly the rounded div?

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Could you add a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the border to the parent element.

````html
<div class="parent-ele w-72 h-20 border-l-4 border-l-yellow-500">
   <div class="rounded-2xl">
   </div>
</div>
```
````